# What is 'Category Affiliation' in sociolinguistics?

Tags: terminology, sociolinguistics, variation

I came across this term in a paper talking about the first wave and second wave studies. Anyone know what it means?

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of context: I assume you mean the first wave and second wave of *feminism*. Can you please link the paper?